# Teensy 3.2 SPI default MOSI no output

Tags: arduino, spi, teensy

I've made a simple SPI test for Teensy 3.2 board.

While trying to get the communication up and running I noticed that while the alternative SCLK pin14 generated the clock, no MOSI data was outputted from the default DOUT pin11 of the Teensy 3.2 board.
I checked the levels with an oscilloscope.

I set the alternative MOSI pin and voila, that pin works fine.

By calling SPI.begin() I assume the default pins are configured:
MOSI pin 11
SCLK pin 13 (but used by LED so I use alternative on pin 14)
nCS pin 10 (I do control it manually, as stated in Arduino documentation)

**For some reason pin 11 doesn't work, even when I try to declare it manually.**

**Whoever can try and test it out as well , please see the Arduino code attached.
Do you have issues as well or am I missing here smth ?**

Arduino code (no actual chip required):
**Commenting or uncommenting  //#define ALT_DOUT  helps to select the correct pin easily.**

```
#include <SPI.h>  // include the SPI library:


//#define ALT_DOUT //DEBUG Select Teensy DOUT location
#define OSC     //Use PWM input of the MAX chip

// === PIN Definitions ==== //
const int led = 13;

//MAX6967 === SPI

#ifdef ALT_DOUT
  const int MAX6967_DIN = 7;  //Using Alternative pin to send data out
#else  
  const int MAX6967_DIN = 11;  //Teensy 3.2 default doesn't seem to work
#endif
  
const int MAX6967_SCLK = 14; //Configured as Aleternative. on Rising edge, data shifts.
const int MAX6967_nCS = 10;  //Must be low to data to enter. Recent 16bit latch on rising edge of nCS
const int MAX6967_DOUT_OSC = 11;
   

// === Control ===
/*
uint16_t MAX6967_D15; //Read / Write

//Register Aadresses
uint16_t MAX6967_P0_REG = 0x00;  
//uint16_t MAX6967_P1_REG = 0x01;

uint16_t MAX6967_CNFG_REG = 0x10;

uint16_t MAX6967_RUN_NORAMPUP =  
*/



//LED intensity control
//Individual 8-bit PWM per CC output
//Individual 1bit analog
//Global 3bit analog control to all outputs


// === Data === //


// === DEBUG ===
char dbuf[100]; //Debug sprintf buffer
int once = 1;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600); //USB
  
  SPI.begin();
  MAX6967_init(); //Led driver specific inits

  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    
  MAX6967_write(0x82, 0x04);
  
  delay(1000);
}


// ====== Custom functions =====

void MAX6967_init(void){ 

  #ifdef ALT_DOUT
    SPI.setMOSI(MAX6967_DIN);
    digitalWrite(MAX6967_DIN, 0);
  #else
    //SPI.setMOSI(MAX6967_DIN); not even with this.
    //otherwise SPI.begin should init the default, right ?
    pinMode(MAX6967_DIN, OUTPUT);
  #endif
    Serial.println(MAX6967_DIN);
  
  SPI.setSCK(MAX6967_SCLK); //Use the alternative on pin 14
  pinMode(MAX6967_nCS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MAX6967_DOUT_OSC, OUTPUT); //Set as DOUT

  digitalWrite(MAX6967_SCLK, 0); //Clocked on the rising edge, so default is low.
  digitalWrite(MAX6967_nCS, 1);
  //digitalWrite(MAX6967_DOUT_OSC, 0); //if set as DOUT
  
}

void MAX6967_write(uint8_t address, uint8_t value) {
  
  // [R/W][D14 - D8]{D7 - D0] 
  address &= ~(1 << 7); //The MSB bit of the address is R/W - 1/0
  
  //address |= (1 << 7); //The MSB bit of the address is R/W - 1/0

  // take the SS pin low to select the chip:
  digitalWrite(MAX6967_nCS,LOW);
  //  send in the address and value via SPI:
  SPI.transfer(address);
  SPI.transfer(value);
  // take the SS pin high to de-select the chip:
  digitalWrite(MAX6967_nCS,HIGH);

  sprintf(dbuf, "address: %04X Value: %04X \r\n", address, value);
  Serial.print(dbuf);
  
}
```

Comment: Try a stock example for the board absolutely 100% exactly as published, even if you don't have the corresponding target chip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah, I now found my error!

I can, indeed set alternative pins separately (as one should).

**Error was in my code where I accidentally pinned OSC_DOUT pin also to 11 and set it to LOW in MAX6967_init().**

```
//const int MAX6967_DOUT_OSC = 11; //<=== This here was the mistake along with setting this to LOW after the _DIN define.
```

Once corrected / removed, the default MOSI and alternative SCLK worked together nicely.

Example code:

```
#include <SPI.h>  // include the SPI library:


//#define ALT_DOUT //DEBUG Select Teensy DOUT location
#define OSC     //Use PWM input of the MAX chip

// === PIN Definitions ==== //


//MAX6967 === SPI
#ifdef ALT_DOUT
  const int MAX6967_DIN = 7;    //Using Alternative pin to send data out
  const int MAX6967_SCLK = 14;  //Configured as Alternative. on Rising edge, data shifts.
  const int led = 13;           //on-board LED available
#else  
  const int MAX6967_DIN = 11;   //As using defaults, no real need to define these.
  //const int MAX6967_SCLK = 13;  //Mind the LED
  const int MAX6967_SCLK = 14;  //Mind the LED
#endif
  
const int MAX6967_nCS = 10;  //Must be low to data to enter. Recent 16bit latch on rising edge of nCS

//const int MAX6967_DOUT_OSC = 11; //<=== THis here was the mistake along with setting this to LOW after the _DIN define.
   

// === Control ===
/*
uint16_t MAX6967_D15; //Read / Write

//Register Aadresses
uint16_t MAX6967_P0_REG = 0x00;  
//uint16_t MAX6967_P1_REG = 0x01;

uint16_t MAX6967_CNFG_REG = 0x10;

uint16_t MAX6967_RUN_NORAMPUP =  
*/



//LED intensity control
//Individual 8-bit PWM per CC output
//Individual 1bit analog
//Global 3bit analog control to all outputs


// === Data === //


// === DEBUG ===
char dbuf[100]; //Debug sprintf buffer
int once = 1;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600); //USB
  
  SPI.begin();
  MAX6967_init(); //Led driver specific inits

  //pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  //digitalWrite(led, HIGH);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    
  MAX6967_write(0x82, 0x04);
  
  delay(1000);
}


// ====== Custom functions =====

void MAX6967_init(void){ 

  #ifdef ALT_DOUT
    SPI.setMOSI(MAX6967_DIN);
    SPI.setSCK(MAX6967_SCLK); //Use the alternative on pin 14

    digitalWrite(MAX6967_DIN, 0);
    digitalWrite(MAX6967_SCLK, 0); //Clocked on the rising edge, so default is low.
  #else
    //Use defaults !
    //Test if default MOSi with alternative SCLK works ?
    SPI.setSCK(MAX6967_SCLK); //Use the alternative on pin 14
    digitalWrite(MAX6967_SCLK, 0); //Clocked on the rising edge, so default is low.
  #endif
    Serial.println(MAX6967_DIN);
  
  pinMode(MAX6967_nCS, OUTPUT);
  //pinMode(MAX6967_DOUT_OSC, OUTPUT); //Set as DOUT

  digitalWrite(MAX6967_nCS, 1);
  //digitalWrite(MAX6967_DOUT_OSC, 0); //if set as DOUT
  
}

void MAX6967_write(uint8_t address, uint8_t value) {
  
  // [R/W][D14 - D8]{D7 - D0] 
  address &= ~(1 << 7); //The MSB bit of the address is R/W - 1/0
  //address |= (1 << 7); //The MSB bit of the address is R/W - 1/0

  // take the SS pin low to select the chip:
  digitalWrite(MAX6967_nCS,LOW);
  //  send in the address and value via SPI:
  SPI.transfer(address);
  SPI.transfer(value);
  // take the SS pin high to de-select the chip:
  digitalWrite(MAX6967_nCS,HIGH);

  sprintf(dbuf, "address: %04X Value: %04X \r\n", address, value);
  Serial.print(dbuf);
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>IIRC, on the Teensy 3.x the primary and alternate pins can only be switched as a group, not individually (i.e. no mix and match).  If you want to use the primary clock you must use the primary data pins.  The same goes for the alternates.</strike>

> Edit: The above may only be true when using certain SPI libraries (such as the Teensy-specific ones whose names end in `_t3`).  As @crypton found, the alternate pins can (at the hardware level) be freely mixed and matched (refer to his/her/their answer for details).  Leaving this answer as-is for posterity.

---

After having taken another look at the [MK20DX256VLH7 datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/K20P64M72SF1RM.pdf) I see nothing that would indicate that this is a hardware limitation<sup>1</sup>.  However, I have run into similar issues in the past with this board so I suspect any issues lie in the SPI library, not the silicon.

<sup>1</sup> Nothing in the datasheet mentions such a limitation and §10.2.4 note 2 (p. 207) implies that (alternate) pins can be freely assigned.

Comment: ah, I now found my error!
I can, indeed set alternative pins separately (as one should). 
Error was in my code where I accidentally pinned OSC_DOUT pin also to 11 and set it to LOW. Once corrected / removed, the default MOSI and alternative SCLK worked together nicely.

I mark this as useful as this led me to investigate this further in terms of testing different alternative pins together and leading me to the mistake made.

Comment: @crypton Good to know.  Like I mentioned I've run into this issue myself; perhaps the issues I encountered are similar to the ones you did.

Comment: Yup, good to know. I am aware there are some Teensy specific libraries (claimed to be faster) which I currently haven't tested yet.

Comment: @crypton The libraries I used are the Teensy-specific ones (names ending in `_t3`).